# Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? - Stacks

Tags: java, methods, stack, counter

I am required to write a method, compress to do the following;

The objective of the
method compress is to remove all null elements from the stack s1. The remaining (non-null)
elements should be kept on s1 in their initial order. The auxiliary stack s2 should be used as
a temporary storage for the elements from s1. At the end of the computation of this method,
stack s2 should have the same content as at the beginning of the computation. See the method
main for an example of the expected behaviour of the method compress.

So far I have;

```
import net.datastructures.ArrayStack;
import net.datastructures.Stack;

public class Stacks {

public static <E> void compress(Stack<E> S1, Stack<E> S2) {

    int counter = 0;
    while (!S1.isEmpty()) {

    }
    if (S1.top() == null) {
        S1.pop();
    } else if (S1.top() != null) {
        S2.push(S1.pop());

        counter++;
    }

    for (int i = counter; i < counter; i++) {

        S2.push(S1.pop());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test method compress
    Stack<Integer> S1 = new ArrayStack<Integer>(10);
    S1.push(2);
    S1.push(null);
    S1.push(null);
    S1.push(4);
    S1.push(6);
    S1.push(null);

    Stack<Integer> S2 = new ArrayStack<Integer>(10);
    S2.push(7);
    S2.push(9);

    System.out.println("stack S1: " + S1);
    // prints: "stack S1: [2, null, null, 4, 6, null]"

    System.out.println("stack S2: " + S2);
    // prints: "stack s2: [7, 9]"

    compress(S1, S2);

    System.out.println("stack S1: " + S1);
    // should print: "stack S1: [2, 4, 6]"

    System.out.println("stack S2: " + S2);
    // should print: "stack S2: [7, 9]"
}

}
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, the code prints the two lines before the compress method and then prints nothing.

Comment: I think when you're cleaning up `S2` you need to do `S1.push(S2.pop());`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Also, the loop `while (!S1.isEmpty())` does nothing, you only ever check one element from `S1`. (Unless that's a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

```java
while (!S1.isEmpty()) {

}
```

Right there, you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

i guess writing the if...else inside your while() as below

```
while (!S1.isEmpty()) {
if (S1.top() == null) {
    S1.pop();
} else if (S1.top() != null) {
    S2.push(S1.pop());

    counter++;
}
```

}

and inside your for it must be something like

```
for (int i = counter; i < counter; i++) {

    S1.push(S2.pop());
}
```

guess it should work

Comment: Loads of help, thanks! Its all working great except for S1 now; the compress method seems to clear S1? Can't see whats wrong:/

Comment: try and debug your code...hope you might spot it where the s1 is being cleared...

Answer (score 0):

I spotted two mistakes in your code. One on each of your cycles.

1. Your `while` loop should be wrapping the conditionals right after
   it.
2. Your `for` loop has its increment variable badly assigned.

Correct version should be:

```
public static <E> void compress(Stack<E> S1, Stack<E> S2) {
    int counter = 0;

    while (!S1.isEmpty()) {
        if (S1.top() == null) {
            S1.pop();
        } else {
            S2.push(S1.pop());
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        S1.push(S2.pop());
    }
}
```

**Edit:** An equivalent `for` loop (maybe you were trying to write this one) may be as follows.

```
for (int i = counter; i > 0; i--) {
    S1.push(S2.pop());
}
```

**2nd edit:** The variables in the `for` loops were switched (S2 was in S1's place and vice versa).

Comment: this is clearing the stack and thowing an emptystackexception :s

Comment: Eclipse console reads:Exception in thread "main" net.datastructures.EmptyStackException: Stack is empty.
 at net.datastructures.ArrayStack.pop(ArrayStack.java:117)
 at QUESTION5.Stacks.compress(Stacks.java:22)
 at QUESTION5.Stacks.main(Stacks.java:45)
stack S1: [2, null, null, 4, 6, null]
stack S2: [7, 9]

Comment: Subtle mistakes are always what troubles us. We need to train our eyes to always double check every name and symbol used. :)